Async providers with nestjs
I am running nestjs and I want to make an async provider. Here is my folder structure
.
├── dist
│   └── main.js
├── libs
│   └── dma
│       ├── src
│       │   ├── client
│       │   │   ├── client.module.ts
│       │   │   ├── client.service.spec.ts
│       │   │   └── client.service.ts
│       │   ├── cmts
│       │   │   ├── cmts.module.ts
│       │   │   ├── cmts.service.spec.ts
│       │   │   └── cmts.service.ts
│       │   ├── dma.module.ts
│       │   └── index.ts
│       └── tsconfig.lib.json
├── nest-cli.json
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── app.controller.spec.ts
│   ├── app.controller.ts
│   ├── app.module.ts
│   ├── app.service.ts
│   └── main.ts
├── test
│   ├── app.e2e-spec.ts
│   └── jest-e2e.json
├── tsconfig.build.json
└── tsconfig.json

I want to make the ClientService an async provider.

I want the Async operation of db connect to run first.
after that any dependent provider can start calling the sendSql() method.

And here are my files:
~/src/app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { AppController } from './app.controller'
import { AppService } from './app.service'
import { DmaModule } from '@app/dma'

@Module({
  imports: [DmaModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}


~/src/app.service.ts
import { CmtsService } from '@app/dma/cmts/cmts.service'
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(private readonly cmtsService: CmtsService) {}
  getHello(): string {
    return 'Hello World!'
  }
}


~/libs/dma/client/client.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { ClientService } from './client.service'

@Module({
  providers: [ClientService],
  exports: [ClientService],
})
export class ClientModule {}


~/libs/dma/client/client.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'

@Injectable()
export class ClientService {
  dbConnection: any;
  async connectToDb(){
    // connection logic...
    this.dbConnection = theConnectionObject;
  }
  async sendSql(sql: string){
   const result = await dbConnection.send(sql) // for example
   return result
  }
}


~/libs/dma/cmts/cmts.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { CmtsService } from './cmts.service'
import { ClientModule } from '../client/client.module'

@Module({
  imports: [ClientModule],
  providers: [CmtsService],
  exports: [CmtsService],
})
export class CmtsModule {}


~/libs/dma/cmts.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { ClientService } from '../client/client.service'

@Injectable()
export class CmtsService {
  constructor(private readonly clientService: ClientService) {}
}


On the nestjs documentation, here's what's written: here
It's written that you can do this:
{
  provide: 'ASYNC_CONNECTION',
  useFactory: async () => {
    const connection = await createConnection(options);
    return connection;
  },
}

But my question is.. isn't it a bad practice to create an instance from the provider ourselves?
Because now I will have to do this:
{
  provide: 'ASYNC_CONNECTION',
  useFactory: async () => {
    const clientService = new ClientService() //  bad practice (?)
    const connection = await clientService.connectDb();
    return connection;
  },
}


You mean when you application starts you need to initiaite DB connection first? Also this will make sure if DB connection exist then start the application ? Am i getting it right

@Sohan, yes that's true

I would not say this is bad practice - instead you are safe gaurding your application. Also this is using the DI principle which makes it flexible and independent.Once the connection is initiated, just inject the model tokens and use in your services. I have done similar pattern but i initiate connection without and service class like yours and inject model tokens in services. this way i do not need any specific service class to create connection. If you want i can show in answer an xample

@Sohan, yes please

This is database.providers.ts where the connection is initiatied
 export const databaseProviders = [
  {
    provide: 'DbConnectionToken',
    useFactory: async (
      environmentSettingsService: EnvironmentSettingsService
    ): Promise<typeof mongoose> => {
      mongoose.set({ strict: false });
      return await mongoose.connect(
        process.env.isApiTestRunning
          ? testDatabaseUrl
          : environmentSettingsService.config.get('usersdb')
      );
    },
    inject: [EnvironmentSettingsService],
  },
];

My schema token provider class - where i inject the schema with initiated connection. MyAppPRoviders.ts
 export const MyAppProviders = [
  {
    provide: modelTokens.UsersToken,
    useFactory: (connection: Connection) => connection.model(dbCollections.users, UsersSchema),
    inject: ["DbConnectionToken"],
  },

You will have to initiate these in your modules - i am assuming you already know this
How to use these schema provider token in services? I will inject below in one of my service class where i want to use the user model to perform DB operation on users collection
Injectable()
export class UserCrud {
    private similaritySearch: any;

    constructor(
        @Inject(modelTokens.UsersToken)
        private usersModel: Model<any>)
    {}
// Your code
//using userModel
await this.usersModel.findOne({}).....
....
}

